# Fatal error after installation of Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2

After installation of **Magento 2.2.3**
store shows below error. I am using **php version 7.2**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Autoload   
\AutoloaderRegistry' not found in /home/user/public_html
/app/autoload.php:37 Stack trace: #0 /home/user/public_html
/app/bootstrap.php(30): require_once() #1 /home/user/public_html
/index.php(22): require('/home/Fatal error/...') #2 {main} thrown in 
/home/user/public_html/app/autoload.php on line 37
```

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this issues comment I hope you got solution on that https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/766